# When should I use message libraries like ZeroMQ/RabbitMQ/ActiveMQ

Tags: sockets, server, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, zeromq

I'm making a small project that contains some Clients and a Server (that manages the clients through a reactor)

I'm wondering if I need to use some sort of message provider library to get them to interact? or just plain sockets will be enough?

So in what **scenarios** should I use these libraries?

Answer (score 2):

**a)**
When some more abstract ( might be even a composite ) **formal-behaviour** communication pattern is to be implemented on top of the just raw point-to-point transport means and some **easy scaling & composition** is needed or expected later.
`{ XREQ/XREP | PUSH/PULL | PAIR/PAIR | PUB/SUB }`

**b)**
When a mix of multiple **transport-classes** is beneficial for your performance goals, using
 `{ tcp:// | ipc:// | inproc:// | epgm:// }`

**c)**
When one does not want to have hands dirty from **scaling IO-processing performance** and has an option to let those issues operated and scaled by dedicated IO-threads beyond of one's own work ( as it is being left towards a set of well-oiled and performance optimised, fine-tuned set of threads inside the central `Context()` and the programming team just enjoys the comfort of operating published messaging methods, without a need to re-spend time on low-level dirty hacks and details **and can concentrate on the domain-specific knowledge, needed for the application under development** ).

Comment: Thank you! Just one question: in c) what do you mean by "scaling IO-processing performance"? can you give me an example where one of these libraries solve it?

Comment: Yes, glad you feel it helpfull. Example is, when one (v)CPU-core ( already locked by an AFFINITY mapping as an exclusive resource for IO-thread is almost not enough for moving all the traffic, or yet gets in conflicting use for input/output operations for different but still prioritised groups of transports ) needs to scale-up and get 2nd, 3rd, 4th ... (v)CPU-core added for doubled, tripled, quadrupled **( almost linearly scaling )** IO-performance. Worth a try to compare the efforts to achieve such scaling w/o an already fine-tuned signalling/messaging LEGO-alike toolbox. Then you realise it.

Answer (score 2):

All the time!

Couple of things to bear in mind:

1). RabbitMQ needs a central server, ZeroMQ does not.
2). RabbitMQ is a proactor, ZeroMQ is a reactor. The latter is IMHO far easier to code for.

Also consider nanomsg. It's similar to ZeroMQ, but has a cleaner design that makes adding additional patterns easier ( and so they have ).

Things like RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ and nanomsg are merely byte shifters. To make them useful it's a good idea to serialise messages. If your system is a single language ( e.g. C# ), then there's nothing wrong in using whatever serialisation facilities are built into that language. However you may also wish to consider something like Google Protocol Buffers, or XSD/XML, or ASN.1, Avro. These are all language independent serialisers, allowing you to develop a distributed heterogeneous system. JSON is attractive in some senses ( everyone's using it ), though from what I've seen of tools to turn JSON schemas into code they're far from mature.

Comment: Salute for **`nanomsg`** + double that for hands-on **`PAR`** occam CSP-experience. Any recent `PAR` language reincarnation in mind?

Comment: SCALA apparently does CSP. But otherwise it's down to 3rd party libraries, or spin one's own.